# How to send assertion from one Service Provider to another Service Provider to enable Single Sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have two service providers(SP) and one common identity provider(IDP).

I can login to both my SP through IDP initiated SSO.
I have same user in both my SP so user lookup is working fine.

After logging in through IDP i have landed in SP1. In SPA i want a link which will be redirected to SP2 landing page without calling the login ti ISP again.

How can i do this?

Comment: Did you come to any conclusion on this? I'm looking to do the same.

Comment: i used to open the direct link of sp2. It authenticated in idp and redirected to sp2 and it worked.